# How to solve this alarm "Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 23.4.0 is not compatible with Xamarin.Forms 2.3.1.111-pre2"?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin Forms and I try to create a Portable app so I can start learning c# and how to create cross-platform applications with Xamarin. I start a new Cross Platform Project using the Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable) template and the .Net Framework 4.6.1. After the solution is created I open the Nuget Package Manager for the Solution and try to update the packages but I get the following alarm.

[image: Unable to resolve dependencies]

As a result of this alarm the Android project is not working. This problem occurred after the recent update of the Windows SDK. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In continuance of my post, I realized that things are easier in Xamarin Studio. The Android project of the multiplatform solution works fine since I'm not updating. In Visual Studio I still have the same problem even without updating a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Jason Give an explanation to this problem in the following link

[Cannot upgrade nuget packages for Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489766/cannot-upgrade-nuget-packages-for-xamarin-android?lq=1)

Comment: True. Jason gives the explanation of the problem. How can I build the Xamarin.Forms application on the Android emulator since I get this alarm?

Comment: uninstall all the packages that depends on xamarin forms including xamarin forms then re-install the xamarin forms package which will include the latest android support packages that forms Supports and rebuild you shouldn't get anymore build errors after that

Comment: I uninstalled all of them and installed it again. No luck. Are there any resources online showing how to treat Nuget Packages?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done about this is only update the Xamarin.Forms package, right now the dll's for AppCompat v4 and v7 are not compatible with the latest version of Xamarin.Forms, I usppose we have to wait for further versions of those packages in order them to fit the dll's versions (also for now (07/04/2016) don't download the latest Android API (24) it has some issues: https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-android-sdk-build-tools-24/)

Comment: BTW you will start to have errors like: 'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'mediaRouteSettingsDrawable' and so, what you need to do is change the  Compile Android Version on the project properties.

Comment: Still not working this way. Any resources online showing how to treat nuget packages?

Answer (score -1):

When I was trying to update the NuGet Packages for one of my Xamarin project, I got the error same as this..

**Please check Compile framework and target framework of your android app.. and update your NuGet packages according to the properties of your android app. Below link describes how did I fix the issue.**

https://xamarinsharp.com/2017/05/01/xamarin-android-support-design-25-3-1-is-not-compatible-with-xamarin-forms-2-3-4-231-constraint-xamarin-android-support-design-23-3-0-how-to-fix-it/